# Is there any functional difference in using Socket or UdpClient for multicasting?

Tags: c#, sockets, multicast

I am familiarizing myself with Multicasting and such.

There are 2 primary examples used:

1. Using `Socket` with `Bind()`
2. `UDPClient.JoinMulticastNetwork()`

One specifiying a [LeaveMulticastGroup](http://www.dart.com/udp-multicast-code-example.aspx) and another [binding and Joining with no LeaveMulticastGroup()](http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/)

What is the difference between the 2 methods of Multicasting, which is preferable to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is in the level of abstraction between using a [`UdpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class and managing your multicast on a lower level, using [sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) and [multicast option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.multicastoption(v=vs.110).aspx). If you use a `UdpClient`, then you don't need to worry about sockets and multicast options, since that is done under the hood in the `UdpClient` class. If you want more control over what is happening, than you can use a more low-level approach with socket and multicast option.

It is probably easier to implement basic multicasting functionality by using a `UdpClient`.

For reference, you can check the following two tutorials (the first uses a `UdpClient` and is more high-level, while the second uses sockets and multicast option):

1. [UDP Multicasting Tutorial](http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/)
2. [IP Multicasting in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C)